# Open a Berkeley 1.85 DB file in Python 3.3

Tags: python-3.x, berkeley-db

I'm working on converting this system I have to Python 3.3. On one end (where I am now), there's a Perl script that generates a large hash table tied to a Berkeley DB file where the keys are numbers and each key has a string associated with it. The other end is another Perl script that takes an integer input by the user, looks up this number in the DB file, and returns the string associated with the number.

I'm looking into alternatives to Berkeley DB down the line since it's not officially supported by Python's standard libraries anymore, but until then I'm trying to replicate this system the best I can so we can just keep doing what we're doing. But the issue at hand is that the Perl module used to make these DB files makes them in v1.85 format, and the bsddb3 module supports only v4.x and up. Is there any way I can get Python 3.3 to handle Berkeley DB 1.85 files?

Answer (score 0):

You can [find this module in PYPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bsddb185/1.0).

I found this via the [python 2 docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bsddb.html#module-bsddb) (scroll down to the 'note').

Comment: Doesn't work. When I build the module I get warnings about assignments and returns making pointers from integers without a cast, and then when I import bsddb185 into a script it raises an ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/bsddb185.so: Undefined symbol "PyString_FromStringAndSize"

Comment: Do you have `python3-dev` installed (assuming ubuntu linux -- what platform is the target)?

Comment: The module source at the above PYPI link is for Python 2, not 3. It could be ported but I don't know anything about porting Python modules and don't think I have the time to learn how for this particular issue.